# Lazy require of extension.binding did not set the binding field

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a `photos.html` that is running on a local php server with a bunch of javascript and html. Whenever I load the page, I get a `(CONTENT_SCRIPT context for elkanacmmmdgbnhdjopfdeafchmhecbf) Lazy require of extension.binding did not set the binding field`. On line one of the file.

Through my research, All the similar questions seem to be related towards working with chrome extensions, so they haven't been helpful. Even if I take out all of the content and run the page, I still get the error.

What is causing this?

I ran my server on my mac with `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` if that's of any use

Comment: Googling the id points to [IdeaMâché Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ideam%C3%A2ch%C3%A9-extension/elkanacmmmdgbnhdjopfdeafchmhecbf).

Comment: I had a similar error - and it was the Honey extension for me. Nice one. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/honey/bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj?hl=en-US

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Googling the id given gives me a link to that app in the chrome store. Deleting the extension from chrome gets rid of the error.

Comment: Thank you, I do not know why Google translate extension fires this problem, it happened when I use npm start to run a webpack server, before this problem happened I just use webpack-dev-server. Anyway, remove and install again solve this problem.